# How do I properly package my Python file and make an installer for it?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a YouTube downloader GUI that I want to be able to share to my friends. It currently consists of a main Python file, a logo png, a settings logo png, and a settings text file. I am not sure how to package this properly, I tried using PyInstaller but for some reason it would not detect the logo png even though both the exe and the png were in the same directory. I also want to know how to be able to make an installer for the exe and all its dependencies possibly using Inno setup compiler or a better program. Attached below is the Python file for reference:

```
icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png"))
```

https://pastebin.com/19k0rFcg

I tried packaging it using PyInstaller but there was an error, the program is unable to find the logo png in the same directory as the program.